# Show w is orthogonal to line

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vectors, inner-products, orthogonality

Show $w$ is orthogonal to the the line $w^Tx + b = 0$

> The way we can prove if two vectors are orthogonal is to show that
> $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b} = 0$
>
> We can say $w^Tx + b = \begin{matrix} w_1x+b, w_2x+b, ... w_ix+b\end{matrix}$
>
> Since $w^Tx + b = 0$ when we find its dot product with $w$ this should also equal $0$. Is this a valid proof?

Comment: In $\mathbb R^n$ that is a plane. Are you working in two dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

In general, the locus of solutions to that equation forms a hyper-plane. To show that $\vec w$ is perpendicular to the hyper-plane we can show that $\vec w\cdot\vec v=0$ for any vector $\vec v$ that lies in the plane.

Any vector in the hyper-plane will have endpoints in the hyper-plane so let $p=(p_1,\dots,p_n)$ and $q=(q_1,\dots,q_n)$ be any two points in the plane. Then $\vec v=(p_1-q_1,\dots,p_n-q_n)$ will be the vector from $p$ to $q$.

$$\vec w\cdot\vec v=\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}w_i(p_i-q_i)=\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}w_ip_i-w_iq_i=\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}-b - -b=0$$

Since this is true for any vector in the plane, $\vec w$ is perpendicular to the plane.

Comment: The vector equation $w^T\cdot x+b=0$  is not of a plane but of a line.

Comment: @WindSoul It is not. In three dimensions, a line has two equations. In $\mathbb R^n$, it has $n-1$ equations because we must eliminate $n-1$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: That is a vector equation not a scalar equation. It comes out from vector equation $w^T\cdot(x-x_0)=0\Leftrightarrow w^T\cdot x+b=0, b=-w^T\cdot x_0$.

Comment: @WindSoul Are you saying that $x_1+x_2+x_3+1=0$ is the equation of a line?

Comment: I say that you’re confusing vector equation of a line with the scalar equations

Comment: I am not. This is a hyper plane. It has equation $w_1x_1+\dots+w_nx_n+1=0$. That has $n$ non-collinear intercepts and forms an $n-1$ dimensional plane. The value $w^Tx$ above is a dot product and so evaluates to a sum of scalar multiplications. You can see that in Shrizzy's expansion.

Comment: If that equation means $\vec b+x\vec w$ where $x\in\mathbb R$ and $\vec b,\vec w\in\mathbb R^n$ then $\vec w$ is not perpendicular to the line. It is parallel. A hyperplane is the only interpretation that makes this true.

Comment: You’re right, is the vector equation of a plane, since vectors x and $x_0$ don’t have to be parallel. Thank you for your input.